# How to display a complex row in jQuery datatables

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, datatables

Currently I am using datatables with `sAjaxSource` and `bServerSide: true`. Got the columns defined in `aoColumns` and the markup is as should be, `table` with `thead` and `th`'s...

I am trying to get some columns I got returned from the server and display them in a `<p>` tag inside the actual row.

For example, right now there are 5 columns returned from the server and there are 5 cells in each `tr` to display them. What I want to do is to change the `table` to display only the first 3 columns that were returned and the other 2 columns will get shown inside a `<p>` tag which will be inside each table row.

Hope I explained myself right.

Comment: Do you mean insert <p> inside td's ?

Comment: Nope. I mean to add a div/p or any other tag inside each row. Maybe change the whole row and compose a new one upon display.. anything that will result in not having to display a single, simple tr row.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use fnRowCallback like this:

```
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
                        $('td:eq(4)', nRow).replaceWith('<p>data1</p>');
                        $('td:eq(5)', nRow).replaceWith('<p>data2</p>');
                        return nRow;
}
```

**UPDATE due the comments:**

So changing callback to "fnCreatedRow" should solve the problem:

```
   "fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {                    
                oTable.fnOpen( nRow, 
                    fnFormatDetails('<div><p>'+aData.columndata+'</p></div>'));
    }
```

Comment: I am looking for a way to not be confined to the td's, so that I can add some more markup like another rows or divs after each line...